# A model's name contains 'cache'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models

In my code, I have a model whose name contains the string 'cache'. For example:

```
class DataCache < ActiveRecord::Base
```

and the table name is `data_caches`. When I run:

```
"data_caches".classify.constantize.new
```

to initialize the model, I get an error like this:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant DataCach
```

Why doesn't this work? I expected "DataCache" but got "DataCach".

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the [Inflections](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html) class in Rails. Add the following text to the `config/initializers/inflections.rb` class:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'cache', 'caches'
end
```

Now in the rails console try out the word:

```
>> "caches".singularize
=> "cache"
>> "cache".pluralize
=> "caches"
```

Answer (score 2):

You should help rails understand how to convert singular to plural in this case. Try to update `config/initializers/inflections.rb` with this name. I think it should solve the problem.